# C++ singleton LNK2019 error

Tags: c++, singleton, lnk2019

I'm trying to write a singleton in c++ - but I got LNK2019 error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  LNK2019 unresolved
>   external symbol "private: __thiscall DBWriter::DBWriter(void)"
>   (??0DBWriter@@AAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class
>   DBWriter * __cdecl DBWriter::getInstance(void)"
>   (?getInstance@DBWriter@@SAPAV1@XZ)    ORCompare

Can someone help me find my mistake?

Here is the h. file:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DBWRITER
#define DBWRITER

 class DBWriter
{

public:

    ~DBWriter();
    static DBWriter* getInstance();

private:
    DBWriter();

    static DBWriter *dbwriter;
};

#endif //DBWRITER
```

and the .cpp file:

```
#include "DBWriter.h"

DBWriter * DBWriter::getInstance()
{
    if (dbwriter == NULL)
        dbwriter = new DBWriter();
    return dbwriter;
}
```

I'll be happy if someone can explain me my mistake.
Thank you.

Comment: Provide the _full_ error message. Are you defining your constructor and destructor?

Comment: I didn't add nothing else to the code

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - I don't understand why you think it's the same question it is not the same problem!!!

Comment: @STF Where's your defintion of `dbwriter`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ in the .h file

Comment: @STF No, that's a declaration. You have to have a _definition_ also.

Comment: @STF Wrong, you only have a _declaration_ in your header file. `static` members must have a _definition_ somewhere, preferably in the class's source file.

Comment: @GregKikola like "dberiter=NULL"?

Comment: No, like `DBWriter *DBWriter::dbwriter = NULL;` in your .cpp file. That will define `DBWriter::dbwriter`.

Comment: @GregKikola In which function should I add it?

Comment: @STF Outside of any function.

Comment: @GregKikola so when it will be happen?